# How to Add Two Columns for a ListView android

Tags: android, listview

I am new in the Android programming
 I need to know How do I add two columns to a listview like this.

[image]

What is called? 
Do I need to modify the XML file only or will I need to modify the Java file too?
This is my Code!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="7"
android:padding="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/galleryImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowColor="#000"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="This is news title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sdetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="This is news description bla bla bla..."/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#42A5F5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="News Author"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#42A5F5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please use Gridview for this not listview.OR you can use recyclerview in which set the layout manager as Gridview.

Comment: Use Gridview for that

Answer (score 0):

you can try using below code for xml changes and Use the Gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/galleryImage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowRadius="1.0"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="This is news title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sdetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#777777"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="This is news description bla bla bla..."/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/author"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="#42A5F5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="News Author"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#42A5F5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use recycler view to show your layout in two columns using Recyclerview set with layout manager as -

```
public class YourClass extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView rv;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm;


// Create custom adapter MyRecyclerView extends to RecyclerView.Adapter
   implements all methods and bind the data inside OnBindView() method on 
   custom design

MyRecyclerView adapter; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_activity);
    rv =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_id);
    rv .setHasFixedSize(true)
    lm = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
    rv .setLayoutManager(lm);
    // get the data of content to be bind on recyclerview with adapter
    adapter = new MyRecyclerView(context, data);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Row Layout and gridview for better result 
you can follow the step from following website,it is a best,
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by making use of a Recyclerview where its LayoutManager is set as grid layout manager.

Answer (score -1):

For that you have to set your LayoutManager as grid layout manager.

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
- https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/][1]